# Would 10 Java classes hierarchy be too much?

Tags: class, plugins, model, abstract-class, hierarchy

I've developed a plugin loading mechanizem, and as a result of the plugins hierarchy design, to be mostly abstract level programming, and with as least high level programming as possible, the plugin class hierarchy of the top most plugins may reach **eight**.

I've been loading tens of plugins to stretch the loading time, and it seem to load quite OK, so I'm wondering what are the bad side effect of the inheritance design, aside of the "**inheritance vs composition**" design issues, things like performance issues, in loading, or run-time.

I would add and say, this is not a plugin model design issue, this is application design issue over the plugin model, should the application know all of its plugins? or should the application define plugins which may have their own plugins that the main application would not be aware of them. The design works for me, and it saves me tones of coding time, the question is how would it behave in run-time?

Thanks in advance,

Adam Zehavi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem with a deep hierarchy isn't so much related to perforfance.
It's more about maintainability of your code. Anyway if you feel to need such a deep hierarchy use it, or post more details.

Of course you have to pay attention to what you are doing. For example:

```
public someClassDeepLevel0{ public void foo(){do something}}
.....
public someClassDeepLevel10 extends someClassDeepLevel9{
public void foo(){
 //do something
 super.foo();
}
}
```

Number of calls to foo() is proportional to how much is deep your hierarchy. If you are doing things like that, then performance could be quite relevant.

Comment: The code is actually very easy to maintain. and the deep hierarchy is necessary to allow a variety of plugins, which would have a their own logic, and models to add to the main application.

Comment: Yes, I though about this issue. There are not too many implemented methods been overridden, most method been implemented may be finalized, the higher level has no use for them, since their logic was already implemented in the parent plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't worry about the numbers. Worry about the design. If the design dictates a deep hierarchy, then so be it. If you value the numbers over the design, maybe you shouldn't be designing.

Comment: Don't patronize, you haven't seen the design or an implementation! I've asked a question out of concern for performance... or something similar, not if you think I should be designing or not.

Comment: @TacB0sS: Wasn't trying to be patronizing, but I was trying to make a point that the design is more important than just counting hierarchy depth. @0verbose pointed out a good *potential* performance problem, but I have no way of knowing if you are having that problem. Generally, if you have performance problems, run the code through a profiler and see where the bottlenecks are. It's *possible* to run into a situation like @0verbose's, but you'll need to provide more details on what the actual code in this hierarchy looks like before we can make better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I would look into the profiler as soon as the application is fully running.